# Valgrind :: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, valgrind

When I run valgrind on my software it gives a condition jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) error. The output from valgrind is as follows:

```
==17787== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17787==    at 0x402688: directory_findname (directory.c:36)
==17787==    by 0x402750: directory_findname (directory.c:41)
==17787==    by 0x402038: pathname_lookup (pathname.c:28)
==17787==    by 0x402239: chksumfile_bypathname (chksumfile.c:55)
==17787==    by 0x4011F9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:143)
==17787==    by 0x4014E9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:182)
==17787==    by 0x4014E9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:182)
==17787==    by 0x40155D: DumpPathnameChecksum (diskimageaccess.c:193)
==17787==    by 0x400F39: main (diskimageaccess.c:80)
==17787==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17787==    at 0x402576: directory_findname (directory.c:27)
==17787== 
==17787== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17787==    at 0x4C2F1BC: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17787==    by 0x4026B6: directory_findname (directory.c:37)
==17787==    by 0x402750: directory_findname (directory.c:41)
==17787==    by 0x402038: pathname_lookup (pathname.c:28)
==17787==    by 0x402239: chksumfile_bypathname (chksumfile.c:55)
==17787==    by 0x4011F9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:143)
==17787==    by 0x4014E9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:182)
==17787==    by 0x4014E9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:182)
==17787==    by 0x40155D: DumpPathnameChecksum (diskimageaccess.c:193)
==17787==    by 0x400F39: main (diskimageaccess.c:80)
==17787==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17787==    at 0x402576: directory_findname (directory.c:27)
==17787== 
==17787== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17787==    at 0x4026B9: directory_findname (directory.c:37)
==17787==    by 0x402750: directory_findname (directory.c:41)
==17787==    by 0x402038: pathname_lookup (pathname.c:28)
==17787==    by 0x402239: chksumfile_bypathname (chksumfile.c:55)
==17787==    by 0x4011F9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:143)
==17787==    by 0x4014E9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:182)
==17787==    by 0x4014E9: DumpPathAndChildren (diskimageaccess.c:182)
==17787==    by 0x40155D: DumpPathnameChecksum (diskimageaccess.c:193)
==17787==    by 0x400F39: main (diskimageaccess.c:80)
==17787==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17787==    at 0x402576: directory_findname (directory.c:27)
==17787==
```

The code itself runs fine and gives me all the output I expect. Also valgrind only gives me this error on a select few inputs to my software. On the majority of the inputs I get no errors what-so-ever. The code section in question is:

```
 const int direntPerBlock = DISKIMG_SECTOR_SIZE/sizeof(dirEnt);
  struct direntv6 buf[direntPerBlock];
  int inodeSize = inode_getsize(&in);
  int ttlBlockNum = inode_getsize(&in)/DISKIMG_SECTOR_SIZE + 1;

  int j;
  for(j = 0; j < ttlBlockNum; j++){
    if(diskimg_readsector(fs->dfd, inode_indexlookup(fs, &in, j), buf)){
      for(i = 0; i < direntPerBlock; i++){
        if(buf[i].d_name[0] != '\0'){
          if(strcmp(buf[i].d_name, dirName)==0){
            if(strlen(name) == strlen(dirName))
              return buf[i].d_inumber;
            else
              return directory_findname(fs, name+(strlen(dirName)+1)*sizeof(char), buf[i].d_inumber, dirEnt);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Where line 27, the supposed uninitalised value, is `struct direntv6 buf[direntPerBlock];`. And line 36 and 37 are

```
    if(buf[i].d_name[0] != '\0'){
      if(strcmp(buf[i].d_name, dirName)==0){
```

The function, `diskimg_readsector(...)` takes `buf` and fills it with the appropriate data. The function is implemented as:

```
int diskimg_readsector(int fd, int sectorNum,  void *buf) {
  if (lseek(fd, sectorNum * DISKIMG_SECTOR_SIZE, SEEK_SET) == (off_t) -1) return -1;
  return read(fd, buf, DISKIMG_SECTOR_SIZE);
}
```

Any clues as to why valgrind is occasionally giving me this issue would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

`dirName' is found as:

```
  // extract the name of the current root directory                                                      
  char dirName[sizeof(dirEnt->d_name)];
  int i = 0;
  while(name[i] != '/' && name[i] != '\0'){
    dirName[i] = name[i];
    i++;
  }
  dirName[i] = '\0';
```

Edit**:

Issues are gone. I just added:

```
struct direntv6 buf[direntPerBlock];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try initializing your data like this:

```
struct direntv6 buf[direntPerBlock] = {0};
```

This way it will never be uninitialized, and unset strings inside should appear empty instead of having garbage inside.  I guess the issue might be with how you're using diskimg_readsector, but I don't see the code for that so can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just added diskimg_readsectors code. On trying to implement your solution I got the compiler errors: `directory.c:31:10: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
directory.c:31:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘buf[0]’) [-Wmissing-braces]
directory.c:31:10: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
directory.c:31:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘buf’) [enabled by default]`

Comment: @rhouli67: that's because of a GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119 - you can work around it by adding more braces, like `{{{0}}}` (experiment to find the right number to add!).

Comment: @rhouli67: reading the `diskimg_readsector()` code now, I see that it returns -1 on failure.  Yet you do not check for this correctly.  That may be part of your problem.

Comment: @Jon Zwinck You are very right, I am checking incorrectly. I fixed the issue but it does not make a difference interms of the valgrind issue. I also played around with the braces and got up to 6 on each side and still no bueno. `directory.c`, the file in question, is compiled as: `gcc -g -fstack-protector -Wall -W -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter -MMD -MF directory.d -std=gnu99   -c -o directory.o directory.c` if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can just use ={0} and ignore the warning.  Or, leave as-is in your original and `memset` it to 0 before use. `memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));`

Comment: Yeah I went the memset route (not sure why I did not do this sooner). `struct direntv6 buf[direntPerBlock];
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));` and all valgrind errors are gone. Still wish I could understand why only some inputs caused these issues when they all ran through this function similarly. Thanks for the help!